# Simple timer with setTimout in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple timer in javascript that counts down from 5 to 0 on a push of a button.  This is my function that I have for the onclick of the button.  I'm getting stuck though since it is not counting down.  Any hints to where my logic is wrong would be apprciated.  Thanks.

```
function countdown(num) {
    if (num >= 0) {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=num;
        timer=setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
        num--;
    }
    else 
        clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is your evaluation of `countdown` as a string was not properly passing `num` along.  Try using a function expression instead.

```
function countdown(num) {
    if (num >= 0) {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=num;
        setTimeout(function () { countdown(num - 1) }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Additionally there is no need for a `clearTimeout` or a global `timer` value.

Comment: nor is there a need for the `timer` variable, or `num--`, correct?

Comment: The logical error was not passing in `num`, however it is acceptable to use strings here, as it just calls eval() on it if you do:          `setTimeout("countdown("+(num-1)+")", 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
button.onclick = function () {
    var n = 5;

    (function loop() {
        label.textContent = n;

        if ( n > 0 ) {
            n -= 1;
            setTimeout( loop, 1000 );
        }
    })();
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/YhBx6/1/